# GDB: how to print content of register at specific address?

Tags: c, gdb, cpu-registers, adc

I am trying to get the contents of my adc register for debugging but I don't know how to print it with gdb. If the address register offset is `0x08` would I use `p/x *0x08`? I am getting a result but it is 64 bits and I'm expecting 32. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that you are going to get anything useful printing from the *offset*. You need the full address, and it will work only in case this register is memory-mapped. This is not a "cpu register" as you tagged it. What is this ADC? IS it  apart of your processor? Or it is some peripheral connected via I2C or similar?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah I'm trying to get the ADC. How would I know what the address to offset from is?

Comment: What ADC? Which hardware are you using?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am using an stm32g0316 disco board. What do you mean by what ADC?

Comment: So your ADC is a built-in peripheral and it is memory mapped. So you should consult you chip [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00371828-stm32g0x1-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and find the memory map. I did it for you and found that ADC is mapped to the `0x40012400 - 0x400127FF` region.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you so much! @EugeneSh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to find the wrong address and using a confusing hex to binary converter. Thanks to @Eugene Sh. for helping.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're trying to derefence a pointer with a known value (0x08 in your case), but GDB does not know its type. Try typecasting it first, i.e. use `p/x *(int*)0x08`.

Comment: I would say use `x/b` instead, but I doubt it is what the OP is after at all (As commented to the OP)

Comment: I am getting the same value back as using `p/x *0x08`. Am I even allowed to look at what is at certain addresses?

Comment: Sorry, meant `x/w` for 4 bytes: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_55.html